# Sending email to a list of users using mailx in subprocess

Tags: python, email, mailx

This code works to send email to a single or more users:

```
msg="My text message"
p1=subprocess.run(["echo",msg],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.run(["mailx -s 'Subject: Hive Alert' 'email1@email.com' 'email2@email.com'< /dev/stdin"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,input=p1.stdout,shell=True)
```

I have a python list

```
users=['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com', 'email3@email.com', 'email4@email.com']
```

How do I send email to a python list by modifying the above code or any other code using mailx in subprocess?

TIA
Shari

Comment: Do you ask how to join strings ?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. This is how you get a [reply all apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_storm).

Comment: @tadman this is not meant for spamming. It is purely for admin tasks.